# Matlab Bug in Sine function?

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

Has anyone tried plotting a sine function for large values in MATLAB?

For e.g.:

```
x = 0:1000:100000; 
plot(x,sin(2*pi*x))
```

I was just wondering why the amplitude is changing for this periodic function? As per what I expect, for any value of `x`, the function has a period of `2*pi`. Why is it not?

Does anyone know? Is there a way to get it right? Also, is this a bug and is it already known?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's actually **not** the amplitude changing.  That is due to the numerical imprecisions of floating point arithmetic.  Bear in mind that you are specifying an integer sequence from 0 to 100000 in steps of 1000.  If you recall from trigonometry, `sin(n*x*pi) = 0` when `x` and `n` are integers, and so theoretically you should be obtaining an output of all zeroes.   In your case, `n = 2`, and `x` is a number from 0 to 100000 that is a multiple of 1000.

However, this is what I get when I use the above code in your post:

[image]

Take a look at the scale of that graph.  It's `10^{-11}`.  Do you know how small that is?  As further evidence, here's what the max and min values are of that sequence:

```
>> min(sin(2*pi*x))

ans =

  -7.8397e-11

>> max(sin(2*pi*x))

ans =

   2.9190e-11
```

The values are so small that they might as well be zero.  What you are visualizing in the graph is due to numerical imprecision.  As I mentioned before, `sin(n*x*pi) = 0` when `n` and `x` is are integers, under the assumption that we have **all of the decimal places** of `pi` available.  However, because we only have 64-bits total to represent `pi` numerically, you will certainly not get the result to be **exactly** zero.  In addition, be advised that the `sin` function is very likely to be using numerical approximation algorithms ([Taylor / MacLaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for example), and so that could also contribute to the fact that the result may not be exactly 0.

There are, of course, workarounds, such as using the symbolic mathematics toolbox (see [@yoh.lej's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159551/3250829)).  In this case, you will get zero, but I won't focus on that here.  Your post is questioning the accuracy of the `sin` function in MATLAB, that works on numeric type inputs.    Theoretically with your input into `sin`, as it is an integer sequence, every value of `x` should make `sin(n*x*pi) = 0`.

BTW, this article is good reading.  This is what every programmer needs to know about floating point arithmetic and functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html.  A more simple overview can be found here: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2):

Because what is the exact value of `pi`? 
This apparent error is due to the limit of floating point accuracy. If you really need/want to get around that you can do symbolic computation with matlab, see the difference between:

```
>> sin(2*pi*10)

ans =

-2.4493e-15
```

and

```
>> sin(sym(2*pi*10))

ans =

0
```

Comment: Plus 1 for suggesting the symbolic math toolbox. I put that in my answer but you showed a working example.

Comment: Thanks. Like you, I doubt it was what OP was really looking for. I thought it's good to get introduced to the symbolic math toolbox and not just think that "matlab can't even tell me that sin(2*pi) is equal 0".

Comment: Thank you so much guys. This is exactly what I am looking for. I am trying to weigh in sine function with other factors, but was having this issue. @yoh.lej solutions brings me back on track. And many thanks to rayryeng for explaining the imprecision in great details. Plus 1 to both of you.
PS: Why -4 on my question, was it too dumb question? :)

Comment: @user3662179 - You can accept one of our answers to signify that you no longer need help on this particular topic.  My guess for the -4 is because this was a non-trivial issue that could have been answered by a simple search.  Some people downvote questions that show no research effort.  I can certainly understand why the "increasing" amplitude may have alarmed you, and for beginners to MATLAB (or any programming environment), this fluctuation is alarming, but all programmers need to know about the basics of floating point arithmetic before they start, which sadly is not taught in schools.